# How to Read / Intercept ADDT mesage sent on Android phone

Tags: java, android, networking, server, ussd

This is a 2 Part Question!

PART A ::

So Till this point all i can figure over was Till Android 4.2.2 there were two ways available to us :

```
Use the logcat and extract information from it Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -v time -b main PhoneUtils:D"); I used this code to read the logcat and find out the "displayMMIComplete" message here

Use the provided intent named "com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService" and listen for this intent and do you task .
```

So what I've acknoweldge till now is, Since 4.0 onwards this intent has been removed and since 4.2.2 onwards printing of USSD message info in the logcat has been removed? Am i right till here And secondly whats the hack or solution now to read the USSD message, there must be some way we can get through it?

PART B::

How can we try and intercept all the packets coming on the phone  , and read the data those packets are carrying ?  What i wanna do with them is, since server send these USSD response to our phone, i wanna know how the android phone receive these packets, What protocol is being used so that  we can intercept those packets and read the data !